# Date to String => Time is missing

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I am trying to convert date to string so I can save this data in firestore. But my getDate func is getting only today's date, not the time

```
struct NewTaskView: View {
@State var taskTitle = ""
@State var taskFrom = ""
@State var taskFromDate = Date()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Group {  // Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
            Text("Task Title")
            TextField("Title", text:$taskTitle )
            Divider()
            Text("From")
            DatePicker("", selection: $taskFromDate, in: Date()...)
                .labelsHidden()
            .onReceive(Just(taskFromDate)) { data in
                    taskFrom = getDate(date: taskFromDate)
            }
            Divider()
        } .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Bold", size: 25))
        .foregroundColor(.gray)

func getDate(date: Date) -> String {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full
let dateTime = formatter.string(from: date)
return dateTime
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getDate(date: Date) -> String {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let dateTime = formatter.string(from: date)
return dateTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
 func getDate(date:Date)  -> String{
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
    let updatedAtStr = "2016-06-05T16:56:57.019+01:00"
    let updatedAt = formatter.date(from: updatedAtStr)
    let result = "\(updatedAt!)".split(separator: " ")
    return String(result[0]+" "+result[1])
    
  }
```